# Installing firmware-b43-installer in terminal, get E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock

Tags: 12.04, wireless, apt, dpkg, broadcom

I am getting the following error message. Please help

```
$sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
[sudo] password for sophon: 
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In terminal run the following:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

This will remove the lock in dpkg. Now run:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Might be you have opened `ubuntu-software-center` or `synaptic` or some other installation program, and thats why you are getting this error message.

Comment: Hi supremum, Thanks a lot That solved the problem!!!!